CMake Resolve undefined references from interface library
I have the following example of a subproject which expects an implementation of extern declared functions. However the linker throws:
undefined reference to mqtt_init in logic.c
projec/subproject/dll/mqtt/DLL_MQTT.h
extern mqtt_init(void);

CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

add_library(My_DLL INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(My_DLL INTERFACE 
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/mqtt/DLL_MQTT
)

set_target_properties(My_DLL PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)

subproject/src/logic.c
include "DLL_MQTT.h"

foo(){
    mqtt_init(); //Call function from mqtt lib
};

CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

set(srcs
    ./src/logic.c)

add_library(SubProjLogic STATIC "${srcs}")
target_include_directories(SubProjLogic PUBLIC ./include)
set_target_properties(SubProjLogic PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
target_link_libraries(SubProjLogic My_DLL)

project/src/mqtt/src/mqtt_impl.c
include "DLL_MQTT.h"

extern mqtt_init(void){
    //Actual implementation of mqtt_init()
}

CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

set(srcs
    ./src/mqtt_impl.c
    )

add_library(MQTTClient STATIC "${srcs}")
target_include_directories(MQTTClient PUBLIC ./include)
set_target_properties(MQTTClient PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)


target_link_libraries(MQTTClient PUBLIC My_DLL)

project/src/main.c
main(){
}

CMakeLists:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(myProject VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

# Software components and wrappers for DLL implementation
add_subdirectory(./src/mqtt)

# subproject
add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/subproject)

add_executable(myProject 
    ./src/main.c
)

target_link_libraries(myProject 
    mqtt
    My_DLL

l2
)

Hi. A specific reason not to write int? int main() int mqtt_init? Soo myProjectdoes not link with implementationMQTTClient`.

@KamilCuk now the references work thanks. However main.c may not call these functions, only subproject/src/logic.c and then it wont get linked again...
